# How to detect a notification in whatsapp to trigger an action in python?

Tags: python, selenium, push-notification, notifications, whatsapp

I want to be able to turn on an led with python everytime i get a notification in whatsapp (for the led part, im using pyserial), but i don't know which tool (Library) can be the best to **detect the notification** and use that to trigger the LED, im a newbie, i've tried with selenium but i just simply don't undestand it enough, i just want to know if selenium is the best way to tackle this problem or there is another tool to solve this.

[Currently im trying to approach this problem by detecting the change in a whatsapp class called "_2gsiG", (i don't know if it is the same class for everyone, but it is the green bubble it appears in the image), because it tells you how many messages you recive in just one chat, when i realize i have to do this for every contact, so i don't think this is an efficient solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTier.png)

Thank you in advance .

Comment: instead of using selenium, have you considered using the [WhatsApp API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/webhooks/inbound/)? You can setup a webhook to trigger your python LED program.

Comment: @khuynh thank you i notice whatsapp API it is a paid service but i'll try it that way

Answer (score 0):

This works looking for the green notification ball and clicks it

```
try:
    search = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_23LrM") # search for the green ball counter notificator in whatsapp web
except:
    search = []

if search != []: # Se detecta notificación
    print("Notification detected!"
    search[0].click()
```